Relabelling equation numbers assigned by align
When using \align, it labels the equations starting from (1), (2), (3), etc., however I would like the labelling to start (5), (6), (7) etc. . Is there any way I can do this within the \align commands?

Welcome! It's not really clear why, but you can do \setcounter{equation}{4} in the document preamble and the first equation will get number 5.

In LaTeX documents, the counter variable that's associated with displayed-equation environments -- not just equation, but also align, gather, and many others -- is called equation. Use a \setcounter directive to set the counter's value to some desired number.
Because the first equation of the four-row align environment is supposed to be 5, the desired value for the equation counter is 4.

\documentclass{article}   % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for 'align' environment
\setlength\textwidth{2in} % just for this example

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{4}  % set the counter's value
\begin{align}
1+1 &= 2 \\
2+2 &= 4 \\
3+3 &= 6 \\
4+4 &= 8
\end{align}

\end{document}

